# onClick of span tag send notification email in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a span tag that is part of a form (but not the final submit form), it advances the user from the first question to the second. Onclick of this button I want to send a simple email notification to a hard-coded email saying that a new entry has been added. I am using WordPress.

My HTML is as follows (can't be changed)

```
<span class="button next email-enter">
    <span class="txt">Get Started</span>
</span>
```

I'm using the following jquery function with ajax (console.log is successful):

```
$('.email-enter').on('click', function(){
    console.log('button is clicked');
    $.post("/wp-content/themes/wptheme/partials/notify.php"); 
});
```

and then I've created a notify.php file that contains the following:

```
<?php wp_mail( 'myemail@myemail.com', 'The subject', 'The message' ); ?>
```

Although the click function works, the ajax/wp-mail is not working (I'm not getting an email). How can I edit this code to send an email notification onclick of this span?

Comment: Did you look into the developer console and look for 404 errors?

Comment: Did you set the right smtp settings?

Comment: When you access `/wp-content/themes/wptheme/partials/notify.php` directly from the browser, does it work?

Comment: No console errors. Not sure about smtp. 

notify.php in the browser results in the following:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_mail() in /srv/www/Operative/wp-content/themes/wpized-light/partials/roi/notify.php on line 3

Comment: @NicoleJ.Patten, your notify.php script lacks an include of a wordpress file which defines wp_mail(). I think vard's answer is the way to go, because notify.php is outside wordpress environment. You have to 1) add it to wordpress environment, or 2) use regular PHP functions, like mail().

Answer (score 4):

It couldn't work because you're trying to use a Wordpress function without being in a Wordpress environment. Even if you placed your script in your theme folder, as you call it directly it doesn't get through the Wordpress Core. If you look into your error log you should see an error saying that `wp_mail` is undefined.

An easy solution would be to just use the PHP `mail` function instead. Though I suggest to do this in a proper way, with [the Wordpress AJAX functionality](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

First, add the following to your theme *functions.php* in order to define a new JS var with the path to *admin-ajax.php*, and set as first parameter the handler name of your script - assuming here *script.js* is where your will do your ajax request:

```
function my_load_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
  wp_localize_script('my_script', 'MyAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts');
```

Then do your request to *admin-ajax.php* (in `js/script.js` then):

```
$('.email-enter').on('click', function() {
    $.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'send_mail'}); 
});
```

Then add the following to your *functions.php* theme file:

```
function ajax_send_mail() {
  wp_mail('myemail@myemail.com', 'The subject', 'The message');
}
add_action('wp_ajax_send_mail', 'ajax_send_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_mail', 'ajax_send_mail');
```

Comment: +1 for a nudge in the right direction, but you really should show how to use the proper `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_localize_script` to get the ajax url: `wp_localize_script( 'my_app', 'ajax', array(
  'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
 ));`

Comment: @cale_b True, the path to _admin-ajax.php_ should be set in this way and not being hardcoded as in my example.

Comment: @vard adding the two functions to my functions.php file and updating the jquery results in the following console error onclick: 

"Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined"

I updated the admin-ajax.php url to be '../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' since the functions.php is inside the wp-content file. Once I get this to work I will try the other method of getting the ajax url.

Comment: @njpatten Yes sorry I edited a bit fast yesterday, you need to pass as first parameter of `wp_localize_script` the same name as you pass for the `wp_enqueue_script` used to register the script where your ajax request will be. See updated answer.

Comment: Old one, but if you have followed this thread and still get "Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined", it is because you need to call the array value from the MyAjax var when you are sending the email. So change `$.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'send_mail'});` to `$.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, {action: 'send_mail'});`

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that your smtp setting are perfect.

```
  $('.email-enter').on('click', function(){
        console.log('button is clicked');
        $.post("/wp-content/themes/wptheme/partials/notify.php"); 
    });
```

`/wp-content/themes/wptheme/partials/notify.php` instead of this try making template file and give permalink in `$.post()` or put file in `wp-content/notify.php`